# How to redirect user to last visited page after signup

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building an ecommerce site that is quite complex with lots of pages. I'm using Node, Express and Passport. I've followed a few answers on this platform and I now use connect-ensure-login to redirect users to the previous page they visited before being asked to login. Everything works well, except that I want to replicate this same thing on the registration route.

This is my login route:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
  successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}), function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.remember) {
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  } else {
    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
  }
});
```

This is my registration route:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    phone,
    password,
    password2
  } = req.body;
  let notifs = [];

  //check if passwords match
  if (password !== password2) {
    notifs.push({
      msg: "Passwords don't match"
    });
    req.flash('info', "Passwords don't match")
  }

  if (notifs.length > 0) {
    res.render('signin', {
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      password: password,
      password2: password2
    })
  } else {
    //validation passed
    User.findOne({
      email: email
    }).exec((err, user) => {
      if (user) {
        notifs.push({
          msg: 'This email already exists'
        });
        req.flash('info', " This email already exists")
        res.render('signin', {
          notifs,
          firstname,
          lastname,
          email,
          phone,
          password,
          password2
        })
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          email: email,
          phone: phone,
          password: password
        });

        //hash password
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt,
            (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser.save()
                .then((value) => {
                  res.redirect('/')
                })
                .catch(value => console.log(value));

            }));
      }
    })
  }
})
```

I want to res.redirect to the previously visited route, instead of the "/" route after registration just as in the login route where it is defined as successReturnToOrRedirect: '/'

NOTE: I have tried req.OriginalUrl and it redirects me to the GET request to the "/register" route

EDIT: I have also noticed that the user is not automatically logged in after registering. I guess this is the reason I can't redirect to the requested page. Please how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I was doing wrong. It was from the "/register" route. When the user successfully registers, the user is not automatically logged in.

To fix this, I just reused the passport.authenticate method to automatically log the user in after sign up.

Here's the updated registration code after the user has been created and the password has been hashed:

```
...

bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt,
            (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser.save()
                .then((value) => {
                  passport.authenticate('local', {
                    successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
                    failureRedirect: '/login',
                    failureFlash: true
                  })(req, res, function () {
                    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                  })
                })
                .catch(value => console.log(value));

            }));

...
```